# Click and drag from inside canvas element highlights text outside it in some browsers

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas in a page with some text after it:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="160"></canvas>
<p>Some text after the canvas</p>
```

I use JavaScript to draw points/lines. This one's very simple.

```
var canvas  = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx     = canvas.getContext("2d");
var drawing = false;

canvas.onmousedown = function(e){
    if( !drawing )
    {
        drawing = true;
        ctx.beginPath();
    }
}

canvas.onmousemove = function(e){
    var x = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

    if( drawing )
    {
        ctx.lineTo(x,y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

canvas.onmouseup = function(e){
    drawing = false;
}

canvas.onmouseout = function(e){
    drawing = false;
}
```

If I click on the canvas and hold, I can move my mouse around in the canvas and draw lines. Great! However, if I keep holding and move my mouse down off the canvas and past the `<p>` text, I will end up highlighting that text. Not so great! I've noticed this doesn't happen in some browsers. Here is a list of what I've tested on:

- Firefox 37: no highlighting issue exists
- IE 9: highlighting issue exists
- IE 11: highlighting issue exists
- Chrome 41: highlighting issue exists

My question: What can be done to prevent this highlighting issue from occurring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can dissable text selection onDrag:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zb2soupb/

```
.unselectable {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}


canvas.onmousemove = function(e){

    // Dissable text selection
    document.body.classList.add('unselectable')

    var x = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

    if( drawing )
    {
        ctx.lineTo(x,y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

canvas.onmouseup = function(e){
    drawing = false;
    document.body.classList.remove('unselectable')
}
```

Comment: This is very close, but it looks like the `classList` property is [not supported in IE9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility), which I need to support.

Comment: Use a pollyfill or use document.body.className = "unselectable". However this is the way to do it

Comment: Right now I've gotten it resolved in everything but IE9. `document.body.className = "unselectable"` indeed adds the class, but text is still able to be selected in IE9. The jsfiddle also fails in IE9. To be extra sure, I made sure it was IE9 compat mode with IE9 standards. Previously it was IE7 standards for some reason...

Comment: Here you go, In IE9 just return false on mousedown: http://jsfiddle.net/zb2soupb/2/

Comment: Haha, just did that a few seconds before this comment came up. Now everything is working. Feels a little hack-y, but when doesn't IE feel hack-y? :P

Comment: Its not "hack-y", its the way we do things in IE :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer is to call "e.preventDefault()" inside all your canvas mouse event handlers, e.g.:

```
canvas.onmousedown = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    // <-- this
    if( !drawing )
    {
        drawing = true;
        ctx.beginPath();
    }
}
```